# Combining development and support departments

Tags: teamwork, workflows, support, technical-support

I'm the manager of a reasonably small sized development department with 13 developers, 5 testers/QA, and 2 UX-designers.

The support is split into two parts "Customer service" (CS) and "technical support" (TS). However, today these are quite intertwined. TS and CS share the burden of answering phones and reroutes questions to each other. TS answers difficult technical questions and troubleshoot issues with the customers. CS takes care of light tech questions, added sales, onboardings, etc. If TS can't solve an issue (for example due to a bug) the tickets are transferred to the dev team.

---

This leaves me with the opportunity to suggest absorbing the technical support team under "my wings", instead of customer service. I have no personal gains in this, I am considering this purely for the benefit of the company.

**Perceived benefits**

What I think will come out of this is mainly a better product and a more closed loop between QA and TS. At this point it's easy to move responsibilities between them. For example who reproduces an issue before sending it to the relevant dev team?

Also, today feedback is pretty much limited to **major issues and bugs** instead of everything between major grievances and irritations.

**Drawbacks**

I am the manager for the entire development department. Each team has a sort of team leader, but they basically just escalade issues to me. This is something I have to address sometime soon in any case. Incorporating a new team with mine would cause increased administrative duties, such as SLA reporting (and following) which could be pretty mentally taxing.

**Changes I would do as a part of my proposal**

Today, customer service and technical support is quite intertwined and I don't want any part of the sales side, so what I would suggest is the following:

1. No inbound calls to technical support. Customer service answers all calls and acts as first line. They are smart people, any technical issues they can answer quickly, they will.
2. Technical support is currently 3 people. One of those will remain in the CS department to help answer 1st line. So in reality only two people will join my team.
3. Support tickets will arrive through Jira as per usual, but TS will only look at second (and third) line.
4. It will also be possible to connect directly to a support technician, but at the discretion of the CS representative. You can't call directly to TS but you can be connected. This is to avoid TS having to spend a lot of time calling out to customers that won't respond.
5. Developers are **never** the fallback for technical support, or 1st line. If there are multiple sick people, vacations colliding etc, the support temporarily morphs back into customer care.

What do you think?

TLDR: I have the opportunity to absorb the technical support team into my development team, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's tempting to think that customers reporting bugs to developers is useful and hence moving the TS team to be closer to dev can improve the product. But this is rarely the case.

Your dev and test teams are creating a product to a spec. they make compromises based on time and budget. Ideally there are zero defects.

Customers tell you whether the spec is any good for them.

Now if you have a small team of devs and a small number of technical customers, sometimes working directly with the customer is a good thing. The customer becomes a stakeholder in the product and will be pushing feature requests directly to the devs. The devs get a better understanding of the customers problems and create features which are a good fit for that customer.

However! this only works at the start. It doesn't scale up, because you cant have multiple customers all with different goals all try and get their feature developed.

The business needs to evaluate its customers as a whole, decide which features will create the most profit and spec them out.

Rather than relying on customers to tell you when there is a bug, you should improve your testing and add analytics. You should know before your customers and be calling them up to apologise and offer a fix.

Your CS and TS teams should concentrate on making customers happy by training and helping them use your product.

Bugs should never be reported. They should be found via testing and analytics, this should be your goal to work towards, rather than making bugs easier to report.

Comment: Just to clarify, the dev team will not act directly on customer feedback, but need to be aware of the customer feedback. We get manual bug reports, as well as automatic bug reports via sentry, error log scraping etc, but I think we miss a lot of casual annoyances this way. The dev teams work in autonomous teams where they have a lot of decision capabilities. I want them to have as much data as possible to paint the way forward.

Comment: yeah, im saying talking to TS is not the way to get useful data. do a survey or measure with metrics etc